# ¿Como hacer que me salga en consola el fichero leido?

Tags: java

Tengo esto de codigo. En un Cocineros.txt tengo la informacion relacionada con los Cocineros, pero no consigo hacer que me leea y me aparezca en cosola.
Esto es mi codigo de lecturaDeFichero:

```
    public static ArrayList<Cocinero> leerCocineros() 
        {
            ArrayList<Cocinero> retorno = new ArrayList<Cocinero>();
            File f = new File ("C:/workspace/Cocineros.txt"); 
            FileReader fr;
            try 
            {
                fr = new FileReader (f);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
                String linea = br.readLine();
                String[] lineaSeparada;
                while(linea!=null)
                {
                    linea= br.readLine();
                    lineaSeparada=linea.split(";");
                  
    
 
 retorno.add(newCocinero(lineaSeparada[0],lineaSeparada[1],Integer.parseInt(lineaSeparada[2]),lineaSeparada[3],lineaSeparada[4],lineaSeparada[5]));
                    
                }
                
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

Comment: De favor pon el código en donde llamas al método leerCocineros y donde muestras resultado para tener más claridad. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como seria la lectura de fichero en Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String cadena;
            while ((cadena = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(cadena);         
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Creo que tu problema puede estar en que le indicas mal la ruta de tu fichero, fíjate en el ejemplo como se utilizan las doble barras invertidas `\\`.

Después se lee el fichero hasta el final  y vas mostrando línea por línea el contenido en cuestión.

**Output**

```
hola
adios
hola
adios
hola
adios
hola
adios
hola
adios
```

Answer (score 0):

No estas iniciado el array **lineaSeparada**:

```
 String[] lineaSeparada = new String[6];
```

Igualmente este es un pequeño test que arme para probar si funciona:

```
public class Cocinero {
String nombre;
String tipo;
int edad;

public Cocinero(String nombre, String tipo, int edad) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.edad = edad;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "nombre: " + nombre + ", especialidad: " + tipo + ", edad: " + edad;
}

public static ArrayList<Cocinero> leerArchivo() {
    
    ArrayList<Cocinero> ref = new ArrayList<Cocinero>();
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("cocineros.txt"); // la ubicación del archivo
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String cocinero;
        String[] data = new String[3];
        
        while( (cocinero = br.readLine()) != null) {
            
            data=cocinero.split(";");
            ref.add( new Cocinero(data[0], data[1], Integer.parseInt( data[2]) ) );
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error al leer lina del archivo");
    }
    finally {  // no le prestes atencion a los close los puse por el ide
        if(fr != null)
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar el archivo");
            }
        if(br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error al cerrar el buffer de lectura");
            }
        }
    }
    return ref;
}
```

}

Mi archivo tiene la forma:

```
nombre;especialidad;edad

Lucas Martin;Pastelero;32
Maria Laura;Chef;29
```

La llamada o uso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Cocinero> cocineros;
    cocineros = Cocinero.leerArchivo();
    
    for (Cocinero t : cocineros) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```